# Are there any Android tablets that have the "negative colours" accessiblity feature like the Samsung Galaxy S III phone has?

Tags: tablet, screen, accessibility

Are there any Android tablets that support the "negative colours" accessibility setting like the Samsung Galaxy S III phone does?

There are many people like myself whose vision is light sensitive and as such find it much more comfortable to read off screens that have a black background with light coloured text e.g. white text on a black background. Reading black text on a white background (the usual way round) gives me bad headaches.

The iPhone and iPad have long had an accessibility feature called "white on black" which basically negates all the colours globally - looking something like a photo negative. I was very glad when I saw that the Samsung Galaxy S III supports such a feature - they call it "negative colours" - basically making any app which has a light coloured background much more comfortable to view.

I'm after an Android tablet that can do this, not a phone. However, from what I've read, the Samsung Galaxy tablet doesn't seem to have this feature. I'm wondering if there are any other Android tablets that do.

The inverted colours setting I'm after is a global colour negation, so everything (all apps, home screen, built in OS screens etc.) need to have negative colours. I think on the iPhone, iPad and Samsung Galaxy S3, this is done at the video device driver level to achieve this globally throughout the OS and all Apps.

Are there any Android tablets that provide the "negative colours" accessibility feature?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Samsung Tab 3 8.0 and others. The Samsung Galaxy S III phones got this feature quite a while before it was part of the feature set of the Samsung tablets. Other Samsung tablets like the Note also appear to have this feature now, as do later versions of the Galaxy phone. I still haven't come across any other manufacturer who includes this accessibility feature with their Android tablet range.

(for any users who need high contrast to read or have a light sensitivity problem, this feature is a life saver)